# std::unique_ptr<T[]> with an array of derived objects, use of deleted function

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, polymorphism, unique-ptr

In my code for numerical physics, I need to create an array of Derived objects using the `unique_ptr` with their type being the Base class. Normally, I would have:

```
// Header file of the Base class
class Particle{
public:
    Particle();             // some constructor
    virtual ~Particle();    // virtual destructor because of polymorphism
    virtual function();     // some random function for demonstration
};

// Header file of the Derived class
class Electron : public Particle{
public:
    Electron();
    // additional things, dynamic_cast<>s, whatever
};
```

Later in my code, to create an array of Derived objects with the Base type pointer, I would do

```
Particle* electrons = new Electron[count];
```

The advantage is that I am able to use the array in a really convenient way of `electrons[number].function()`, because the incremental value in `[]` is actually the address of the memory that points to the proper instance of the object `Electron` in the array. However, using raw pointers gets messy, so I decided to use the smart pointers.

Problem is with the definition of the Derived objects. I can do the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<Particle, std::default_delete<Particle[]>> electrons(new Electron[count]);
```

which creates the array of polymorphic Electrons and uses even the proper call of `delete[]`. The problem lies in the way of calling the specific objects of the array, as I have to do this:

```
electrons.get()[number].function();
```

and I don't like the `get()` part, not a little bit.

I could do the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<Particle[]> particles(new Particle[count]);
```

and yes, call the instances of `Particle` type in the array with the

```
particles[number].function();
```

and everything would be fine and dandy, except for the part that I am not using the specific details of the class `Electron`, therefore the code is useless.

And now for the funny part, let's do one more thing, shall we?

```
std::unique_ptr<Particle[]> electrons(new Electron[count]);
```

BOOM!

```
use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>::unique_ptr(_Up*) [with _Up = Electron; <template-
 parameter-2-2> = void; _Tp = Particle; _Dp = std::default_delete<Particle []>]’
```

What is going on?

Comment: The error is only a symptom of a design issue.  Your design should best distinguish the creation of the array (keeping in mind that arays are not hemselves polymorphic) and the polymorhic use of the array.

Comment: Do what you want with this comment, as it might be completely off-track and/or way too much work to implement but.... my personal experience with (physics) simulations/numerical experiments is that everything is known compile-time. It strikes me as a little odd therefore that you're using virtual functions which can seriously slow a program down. Up to now I have managed to avoid these run-time things altogether.

Comment: Compile-time BOOMS are your best friend. :-)  This is a feature of `unique_ptr` which turns run time errors into compile time errors.

Comment: @JorenHeit Yes, things are known at compile time, that is correct, however I am also trying to make the coding clean. For instance, in this direct example, I am working with Ions and Electrons and many things can be quite conveniently polymorphed, so I don't copy-and-paste everything all over again. If that is what you meant.

Comment: I rolled back because solutions don't belong in answers on SO, we are different. ([A current meta-question about cleaning up such things](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309266/actively-prevent-this-in-title-solved)) Anyway, you already did do it the SO way too!

Comment: "The advantage is that I am able to use the array in a really convenient way of `electrons[number].function()`"...[that's UB](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#6).

Comment: Do you need polymorphism here? All particles have mass, charge (0 for neutrons) etc. Just add them as members to a particle class. Or create a collection of data objects for each type of particle, and particles point to them.

Comment: Well you can avoid copy-paste without runtime polymorphism. One option would be a more general particle-class with properties like mass, charge etc, like @NeilKirk already suggested. There are more options, but we'd have to know more about your particular requirements. If you do continue this design, be sure you know that the performance impact can be significant even on modern hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<Particle>[]>` if you want to keep close to your current code and are tracking the count separately anyway.

Be aware that that won't get you around the additionaly indirection though, and if you can, using a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Particle>>` and thus including the length and a judicious use of `reserve` should not be slower.

Comment: Ah, right as i posted my solution, I read your (exactly the same) response. :-)

Answer (score 10):

`std::unique_ptr` is preventing from shooting yourself in the foot, as `std::default_delete<T[]>` calls `delete[]`, which has the behaviour specified in the standard

> If a delete-expression begins with a unary :: operator, the
>   deallocation function’s name is looked up in global scope. Otherwise,
>   if the delete-expression is used to deallocate a class object whose
>   static type has a virtual destructor, the deallocation function is the
>   one selected at the point of definition of the dynamic type’s virtual
>   destructor (12.4). 117 **Otherwise, if the delete-expression is used to
>   deallocate** an object of class T or **array** thereof, the **static and
>   dynamic types of the object shall be identical** and the deallocation
>   function’s name is looked up in the scope of T.

In other words, code like this:

```
Base* p = new Derived[50];
delete[] p;
```

is undefined behaviour.

It may have seem to work on some implementations - there, the `delete[]` call looks up the size of the allocated array and calls destructors on the elements - which requires the elements to have a well known size. Since the size of derived objects may differ, the pointer arithmetic goes wrong, and the destructors are called with the wrong address.

Let's review what you tried:

```
std::unique_ptr<Particle[]> electrons(new Electron[count]);
```

there's a code in `std::unique_ptr`'s constructor that detects these violations, see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr).

```
std::unique_ptr<Particle, std::default_delete<Particle[]>> electrons(new Electron[count]);
```

is undefined behaviour, you essentially tell the compiler that `delete[]` is a valid way to release the resources you push to the constructor of `electrons`, which isn't true, as mentioned above.

[...but wait, there is more (priceless comment by @T.C.):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461724/stdunique-ptrt-with-an-array-of-derived-objects-use-of-deleted-function/33461842?noredirect=1#comment54716534_33461724)

> For addition or subtraction, if the expressions P or Q have type “pointer to cv T”, where T and the array element type are not similar ([conv.qual]), the behavior is undefined. [ Note: In particular, a pointer to a base class cannot be used for pointer arithmetic when the array contains objects of a derived class type.  — end note ]

This means not only deleting an array is undefined behaviour, but so is indexing!

```
Base* p = new Derived[50]();
p[10].a_function(); // undefined behaviour
```

What does it mean to you? This means *you shouldn't use arrays polymorphically*.

The only safe way with polymorphism is to use `std::unique_ptr` pointing to derived objects, like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Particle>>` (we don't have polymorphic use of array there, but arrays with polymorphic objects there)

Since you mention that performance is critical, then dynamically allocating every `Particle` will be slow - in this case you can:

- use an object pool
- make use of flyweight pattern
- refactor it to avoid inheritance
- use `std::vector<Electron>` or `std::unique_ptr<Electron[]>` directly.

Comment: But I was using it this way the whole time and it worked. I am just stunned now... How am I supposed to create this array, then?

Comment: @bluecore That's how undefined behaviour works. Invalid code may seem to run correctly, but crash on the newer compiler or after any code change. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: std::unique_ptr<Electron[]> and that's what I am thinking about right now. Even though I would have to implement templates to the other areas of the code, as I am using Ions also. That was the reason I needed to have the same Base type.

Comment: Your `new[]` code is completely batshit insane and does not work at all. Any observations you may have made of it working are pure chance and nothing more.

Comment: For your first quote, [\[expr.delete\]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#3)  seems more directly on point.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with your design is that **objects** are derived and polymorphic, but not the arrays of objects.

For example,  `Electron` could have additional data that a `Particle` doesn't have. Then the size of an `Electron` object would no longer be the same size as a `Particle` object.  So  the pointer arithmetic that is needed to access array elements would not work anymore.

This problem exist for raw pointers to array as well as for `unique_ptr`to array.  Only the objects themselves are polymorphic.  If you want to use them without the risk of [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing),  you'd need an array of pointers to polymorphic objects.

If you look for additional arguments explaining why this design should be avoided, you may have a look at the section of Scott Meyers' book "More effective C++" titled "Item 3: never treat arrays polymorphically".

### Alternative: change your design

For example, use a `vector` of the real type to create your objects.  And use a vector to a polymorphic `Particle` pointer to use these objects polymorphically:

```
vector<Electron>myelectrons(count);   // my real object store 
vector<Particle*>ve(count, nullptr);  // my adaptor for polymorphic access
transform(myelectrons.begin(), myelectrons.end(), ve.begin(), 
                [](Particle&e){return &e;} );  // use algorithm to populate easlily 
for (auto x: ve)  // make plain use of C++11 to forget about container type and size
   x->function();
```

Here a [live demo](http://ideone.com/SdKejD):

Answer (score 4):

Use a std::vector or std::array (if you know how many) of std::unique_ptr.  Something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:

    A() = default;
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

class B : public A
{
public:

    B() = default;
    virtual ~B() = default;
};

int main(void)
{
    auto v = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>();

    v.push_back(std::make_unique<A>());
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<B>());

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: In terms of speed I did a quick test with the 3 methods and this is what I found:

```
Debug

6.59999430  : std::vector (with reserve, unique_ptr)
5.68793220  : std::array (unique_ptr)
4.85969770  : raw array (new())

Release

4.81274890  : std::vector (with reserve, unique_ptr)
4.42210580  : std::array (unique_ptr)
4.12522340  : raw array (new())
```

Finally, I did a test where I used new() for all 3 versions instead of unique_ptr:

```
4.13924640 : std::vector
4.14430030 : std::array
4.14081580 : raw array
```

So you see there's really no difference in a release build, all else being equal.

Comment: The problem with std::vector<> in my application is that it's slow. Raw arrays are about 30% quicker in access than the dynamically created std::vector. Bear in mind please that the number of particles may be in millions, which makes std::vector<> useless. Array might work, but I am defining the array in header files and something like std::array var; doesn't work, as it needs to know the size at compile time.

Comment: @bluecore: How `std::vector` can be slower than array created with `new[]`?

Comment: You can reserve a suitably large size for std::vector beforehand to avoid a repeated reserve/copy.  I mean you're going to do that with a raw array dynamically created anyway presumably.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Try to do std::vector<double> var; and then double* var = new double[]; with the size of array 10 000 000. Now blast that into a for cycle and do some arithmetic operations and watch the time, you'll be surprised. Not to mention that you actaully have to push_back() into the vector first. And it really isn't that surprising at all. std::vector<> is dynamically allocated field, prone to memory fragmentation etc., whereas new[] is just a simple continuous block of memory.

Comment: Only in debug build.  In a release build it should be almost as fast.

Comment: @bluecore It isn't slower on my compiler with turned on optimizations and release mode enabled. The calls to `operator[]` are inlined, and bound checking is disabled, so it's just as fast as regular arrays. I also use `.reserve()` call to set the size beforehand, and then use `.push_back()`. If all elements are to have the same value initially, I use `.resize()`, which should be even faster with primitive types.

Comment: I edited my answer with my timings.  Most of the time is spent doing the actual allocation for each element of course.  I think the speed difference in release build is down to the iterator checking that's still in the code (that you can switch off with a #define I believe but don't quote me).  I also used unique_ptr for the first two, raw C-style for the raw array.

Comment: That is... interesting.

Comment: Made a final edit - they're all the same speed if you use operator new() for all of the allocations.  There's a slight overhead with unique_ptr (Visual Studio 2013).

Answer (score 3):

Amazingly, nobody yet has suggested just using a polymorphic deleter. The default deleter for unique_ptr is just that- a default. You can change it to do whatever you want, including up or down cast.

It involves some casting, but you can hide that behind a suitable interface if you want.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35bd4c3674d7df07

I would not advise doing pointer indexing with this, though. That would still be totally broken.

Comment: Now that is really interesting, but also feels like a black magic to me too. Also, it might overcomplicate many other things. However, thanks for the answer, might be useful in the future.